# Cannot use System.Object type within WCF WebService

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to create a method using the object type within my WCF WebService, but I get the following error :

[image: Error]

**Interface :**

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
   object GetTwoX(object yo);

}
```

**Class :**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    static public Dictionary<string, List<OPUSInfo>> cache;

    public object GetTwoX(object yo)
    {
        return yo;
    }

}
```

Does somebody know how to pass Object type in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely create a method which takes and/or returns `object`, but as the error says, don't expect the simplistic Test Client to be able to do anything. Use a full-featured service testing application like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to do that.